# call an external api using apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm writing a lambda in node.js that will call an api(post) and gives back the resulting body and the code is as below.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const request = require('request');

exports.handle = function(e, ctx, callback) {
    var bodyDetails = {
        uri: "myURL",
        json: {
            "requestChannel": "web1" },
        "method": "POST"
    };

    callback = ctx.done;
    var data = e.bodyJson || {};
    request(bodyDetails, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body)));
            jsonBody = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
            console.log(body + "\t from suvccess") // Print the json response
            callback(null, jsonBody); // Return the JSON object back to our API call
        } else {
            callback(error);
        }
    });
}
```

and I'm testing the same in my lambda console. by passing a blank json `{}` and I get back the correct response.

Now my next plan is to integrate this piece against API Gateway. So I've created an api for this in my `apigateway` and in that, I've created a resource named `home`. and in the home, I created a `GET` method. with the below details.

```
Integration type: Lambda Function
Use Lambda Proxy integration : checked
Lambda Region: us-east-1 
Lambda Function: myWorkingLambdaName
```

when I tested this using the `test` option given by apigateway. I get the response as

```
Request: /home
Status: 502
Latency: 2942 ms
Response Body
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

when I see my console I see the values of the success block printed, but the status code is 502. This is very confusing, please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: out of curiosity, why wouldn't you use HTTP proxy integration on API gateway, rather than bridging it with lambda? - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API Gateway expects the following properties to be returned from your Lambda:

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

So, instead of `callback(null, jsonBody)`, you should be calling `callback` like this:

```
callback(null, {
    isBase64Encoded: false,
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonBody),
})
```

Comment: Hi, This didn't work for me.
Lambda through api gateway doesn't seem to execute or wait for it to execute the external 'request' at all. As, the console statements within my request block doesn't gets executed, or print anything

Still getting a 502, when lambda tries to make an external api call.

Any help would be deeply appericiated. Works fine on my local machine